# Status dashboard for Multiple Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana

I am traying to find a solution for high-level view of monitoring multiple Kubernetes clusters in single dashboard. I have setup prometheus operator in my multiple Kubernetes clusters as well. But prometheus will not provide that kind of simplicity to monitor multiple Kubernetes clusters with simple dashbaord. Can someone suggest better way of doing it.

May be cluster POD & Node status might be enough. Also let me know is this doable with prometheus API calls to fetch knowhow about the main components of cluster and create a simple web page with those API calls return status. So then based on the API call return vales I can set the status of the dashboard with some color code (Green/Amber/Red). I am referring something similar to following status pages to get quick view of my Kubernetes clusters.

status.webex.com
status.redhat.com

Thanks

Comment: There are open source tools out there to build your own custom status pages https://github.com/ivbeg/awesome-status-pages

Comment: Isnt that what you need [Monitoring Multiple Kubernetes Clusters with prometheus](https://medium.com/thg-tech-blog/monitoring-multiple-kubernetes-clusters-88cf34442fa3) ?

Comment: @Vitalii - no mate. I alredy have prometheus  installed on my clusters

Comment: hey. yes, i agree with you. But " Monitoring Multiple Kubernetes Clusters with prometheus" exactly  shows you configuration needed for prometheus  multiple monitoring. you have  it, need to configure properly. Please let me know where I am wrong

Comment: Hi @Vitalii - Could you please guide me to a correct documentation for "Monitoring Multiple Kubernetes Clusters with prometheus" . So I can try it out